# Divide and Conquer: Statement Explanation

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I have started reading Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H Cormen. In Chapter 4, There is sentence that says

*Subproblems are not necessarily constrained to being a constant fraction of the original problem size*

Can anyone explain this sentence to me. I want to know what do we mean by **constant fraction**. Thanks

Comment: I don't have the book at hand, but I presume it just means you don't always need to *halve* the original problem (or, more generally, you don't always need to make the subproblems an *up-front, given, fraction* of the size of the original problem). (TBC)

Comment: Look at quicksort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort): in the first step we just try to shuffle the elements from the ends towards the middle so that we end up with one element "in the middle" that will be bigger than the preceding but smaller than the following elements. However, the position where this middle element ends up may not be exactly in the middle of the set, so the remaining subproblems may well end up inequal size - one of them significantly bigger and the other significantly smaller than half of the size of the original problem.

Comment: That is the reason why the quicksort, although having very good average and best-case complexity $O(n\log n)$ has not so good worst-case complexity $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This does explain a lot. Now I can move up with my understanding thanks to you.